# Summing values of a column using awk command

Tags: awk

I want to sum the values of all rows in the column 3. How can I do this?

Input:

```
chr19   10 11
chr19   12 15
chr19   11 29
chr19   a0 20
```

Expected output:

`75`

Comment: Just for fun, perl golf: `perl -ape'$s+=$F[2]}{$_=$s' file`

Comment: Just for fun, awk golf: `awk '{s+=$3}END{print s}' file`. Fore! :-).

Comment: @Ed Morton: Everyone is suggesting the same command, but this command misses the value of first row. For my example I get 64 instead of 75.

Comment: You must have some control chars corrupting your input file, probably control-Ms as inserted by Windows programs. Try `cat -v` to see them and `dos2unix` or similar to remove them

Answer (score 59):

```
awk '{SUM+=$3}END{print SUM}'
```

where $3 represent value of column 3

Comment: this command does not add first row of the column. Any solution?

Comment: based on the question not "all rows in the column 3"?...please advise me since the command sums all rows in column three....expected output is 75

Comment: Using the command, I got sum 64 instead of 75. Missing the value of first row.

Comment: is the first row exactly as depicted in the question and all data are seperated by space or more than one space?

Comment: is it possible that you can post the actual data? or is this the actual data?

Comment: `chr19   2006983 2007235`
`chr19   2041129 2041498`
`chr19   2042479 2042848`

@xorg, third column is separated by one space from third column but first and second are separated by 3 spaces.

Comment: for these data try this awk '{print $1}' then awk '{print $2}' then awk '{print $3}'..correspond each column with awks output .from this you will know if awk if capturing all data in each fields...then gave me update..

Answer (score 6):

Just store the value of third column into a variable and add that value with the value present in the third column of next line, likewise for all. Atlast, the variable count contains the sum of all the numbers present in the third column.

```
$ awk '{count=count+$NF}END{print count}' file
75
$ awk '{count=count+$3}END{print count}' file
75
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment. But I got sum 64 instead of 75. Missing the value of first row. I have tried with other input too, but always it is missing the value of first row. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: strange ! how is this possible?

Comment: What's the output of `awk 'NR==1{print $3}' file`?

Comment: Sorry to say, I copied your command and run for my example data and did not return any value. Does it work in your case?

I also used used command (awk '{s+=$3}END{print s}') from previous comment, but it also misses value of first row.

Comment: Thanks again. But my first row in not black. I tried another example of 3*3 matrix data. However, it calculated the last two rows of column 3. 

`chr19   2006983 2007235
chr19   2041129 2041498
chr19   2042479 2042848`

Output was `4084346`  that means `2041498+ 2042848`