# How to find sum of elements in column inside of a text file (Bash)

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a log file with lots of unnecessary information. The only important part of that file is a table which describes some statistics. My goal is to have a script which will accept a **column name** as argument and return the sum of all the elements in the specified column.

Example log file:

```
.........
Skipped....
........

WARNING: [AA[409]: Some bad thing happened.

--- TOOL_A: READING COMPLETED. CPU TIME = 0 REAL TIME = 2

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----               TOOL_A statistics                -----
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           NAME                       Attr1     Attr2      Attr3    Attr4    Attr5
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AAA                                    885        0          0        0        0
AAAA2                                    1        0          2        0        0
AAAA4                                    0        0          2        0        0
AAAA8                                    0        0          2        0        0
AAAA16                                   0        0          2        0        0
AAAA1                                    0        0          2        0        0
AAAA8                                    0        0         23        0        0
AAAAAAA4                                 0        0         18        0        0
AAAA2                                    0        0         14        0        0
AAAAAA2                                  0        0         21        0        0
AAAAA4                                   0        0         23        0        0
AAAAA1                                   0        0         47        0        0
AAAAAA1                                  2        0         26        0        

NOTE: Some notes
......    
Skipped ......
```

The expected usage `script.sh Attr1`

Expected output:
   `888`

I've tried to find something with `sed/awk` but failed to figure out a solution.

Comment: `I've tried to find something with sed/awk but failed to figure out a solution.` please add them here, which will show the effort you've already made...

Comment: for summing columns with awk, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445020/summing-values-of-a-column-using-awk-command

Comment: You have to decide on what is the beginning and end of the table. A particular `TOOL_A statistics` till you get a keyword `NOTE` ?

Comment: @Utsav, yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tldr;

```
$ cat myscript.sh
#!/bin/sh

logfile=${1}
attribute=${2}
field=$(grep -o "NAME.\+${attribute}" ${logfile} | wc -w)

sed -nre '/NAME/,/NOTE/{/NAME/d;/NOTE/d;s/\s+/\t/gp;}' ${logfile} | \
    cut -f${field} | \
    paste -sd+ | \
    bc

$ ./myscript.sh mylog.log Attr3
182
```

Explanation:

- assign command-line arguments `${1}` and `${2}` to the `logfile` and `attribute` variables, respectively.
- with `wc -w`, count the quantity of words within the line that
  contains both `NAME` and `${attribute}` (the field index) and assign it to `field`
- with `sed`

  - suppress automatic printing (`-n`) and enable extended regular expressions (`-r`)
  - find lines between the `NAME` and `NOTE` lines, inclusive
  - delete the lines that match `NAME` and `NOTE`
  - translate each contiguous run of whitespace to a single tab and print the result
- `cut` using the field index
- `paste` all numbers as an infix summation
- evaluate the infix summation via `bc`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I noticed that for some cases the table contains a special last row named `TOTAL` which already represents sum for each column, thus the script will output `expected sum + TOTAL[attr] = 2* expected sum` ... So how to modify the solution to handle this case?

Comment: @Narek, if you can provide an example showing such a `TOTAL` line, then I can try to modify my answer to handle it.

Comment: @NarekAtayan, I've updated my answer to use a better sed expression to print the range of whitespace-containing lines between `NAME` and `NOTE`, exclusive. If you sometimes have a `TOTAL` line preceding the `NOTE` line that you want to ignore, then you can change `/NOTE/d` to `/TOTAL|NOTE/d`.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty (without any other spec)

```
awk -v CountCol=2 '/^[^[:blank:]]/ && NF == 6 { S += $( CountCol) } END{ print S + 0 }' YourFile
```

with column name

```
awk -v ColName='Attr1' '/^[[:blank:]]/ && NF == 6 { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ( $i == ColName) CountCol = i } /^[^[:blank:]]/ && NF == 6 && CountCol{ S += $( CountCol) } END{ print S + 0 }' YourFile
```

you should add a header/trailer filter to avoid noisy line (a flag suit perfect for this) but lack of info about structure to set this flag, i use sthe simple field count (assuming text field have 0 as value so not changing the sum when taken in count)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v col='Attr3' '/NAME/{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) f[$i]=i} col in f{sum+=$(f[col]); if (!NF) {print sum+0; exit} }' file
182
```