# How to sum a certain amount of values from a CSV file?

Tags: csv, awk

On my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, I got a CSV file looking like this:

```
frame,0.291667,2880,,,
frame,0.333333,4569,,,
frame,0.375000,4605,,,
frame,0.416667,4715,,,
frame,0.458333,4804,,,
frame,0.500000,4939,,,
```

and so on...

Comma seperated in *LibreOffice Calc* it obviously looks like this:

```
  | A     | B        | C     
1 | frame | 0.291667 | 2880 
2 | frame | 0.333333 | 4569 
3 | frame | 0.375000 | 4605
4 | frame | 0.416667 | 4715
5 | frame | 0.458333 | 4804
6 | frame | 0.500000 | 4939
```

Now I want to **add the amount of n values of the third column**. For example, add the values C1 to C3 (C1:C3) and after that C4 to C6 (C4:C6).

If I would do that in LibreOffice Calc, I would simply:

```
=SUM(C1:C3) = 12054
=SUM(C4:C6) = 14459
```

Since I want to do automate this, I need some kind of **awk-** command to do this from the **terminal**.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Summing values of a column using awk command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445020/summing-values-of-a-column-using-awk-command)

Comment: No it isn't. I don't want to all the values of a column.
For example, there are 100 rows in that column, but I only want to add the first 24 and then the next 24 and so on...

Comment: Your sample input/output isn't adequate to test a solution against. Don't tell us you need to sum 24 rows at a time, tell us you need to sum, say, 3, rows at a time and then show input with, say, 9 rows and the associated output from that. We need you to provide something **concise** (i.e. we do NOT want to see 100 lines of input!) that we can test a potential solution against . See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: Thanks, edited my question!

Comment: Thanks. I removed the spurious "..."s that everyone would have to remove to be able to use it to test against.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, '{sum+=$3} NR%3==0{print sum; sum=0}' file
12054
14458
```