# How to do arithmetic operations on value returned by uniq -c?

Tags: shell, sed, grep, uniq

I have access log file of Apache web-server. Using Linux/UNIX shell commands I counted number unique dates in a file. Command `uniq -c` returned number of occurences of each unique date in a file. Is it possible to do arithmetic operations with value returned by `uniq -c` or is there any other ways to count occurence and do arithmetic operations? Here is my Linux commads:

```
grep -E [0-9][0-9]/[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2}/[0-9]{4} log.txt | sed 's/.*\(..\)\/Oct\/\(....\).*/\2-10-\1/' | sort | uniq -c | sort -ru | head -10
```

A here is the output:

```
358 2006-10-09
348 2006-10-10
347 2006-10-01
344 2006-10-20
339 2006-10-25
337 2006-10-24
337 2006-10-12
336 2006-10-06
336 2006-10-02
335 2006-10-19
```

Comment: Do you need you want to [sum all the values in the first column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445020/summing-values-of-a-column-using-awk-command)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in a single [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) script that does all the above in a single go (with exception of the sorting). Also, [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) is the tool to use if you want to do arithmetic operations.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ ere="[0-9][0-9]/[A-Z][a-z][a-z]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" }
     (match($0,ere)){ date=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); a[date]++; n++ }
     END { for (date in a) {
              yyyy=substr(date,8,4);
              mm=(index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",substr(date,4,3))+2)/3
              mm=sprintf("%0.2d",mm)
              dd=substr(date,1,2)
              print a[date],a[date]/n,yyyy"-"mm"-"dd
           }
     }' log.txt
```

As you mention that you only want to do this with Linux/Unix Shell commands, I will take the freedom to assume you mean [bash](/questions/tagged/bash). There are many other types of shell, but let us take the most common one.

Well in short, No, it is not possible. [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) does not support floating point arithmetic but you can fake it. Example:

```
$ echo $(( 2/3 ))
1
$ printf "%f\n" "$(( 10**15 * 2 / 3  ))E-15"
0.666667
```

So assuming you have your presented output and lets also assume you have to total, you can do:

```
# total number of dates
n=3417

grep -E [0-9][0-9]/[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2}/[0-9]{4} log.txt | sed 's/.*\(..\)\/Oct\/\(....\).*/\2-10-\1/' | sort | uniq -c | sort -ru | head -10 | \
while read -r count date; do
   printf "%f %d %s\n"  "$(( 10**15 * count / n  ))E-15" "$count" "$date"
done
```

But since you already use [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), I still would suggest [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

Comment: awk is clearly the right approach so, so we don't wast time suggesting other somewhat reasonable approaches only to be told you want to solve without them too - what other best practices and tools do you also want to avoid?

Comment: @AlmasAzimkhan I have added an extra non-awk solution to it.

Comment: @AlmasAzimkhan The result I presented gives the ratio, if you want to have it in `%` you have to multiply with 100.