# How to add the elements in a for loop

Tags: bash, unix

so basically my code looks through data and greps whatever it begins with, and so I've been trying to figure out a way where I'm able to add the those values.

the sample input is

```
35 45 75 76
34 45 53 55
33 34 32 21
```

my code:

```
for id in $(awk '{ print $1 }' < $3); do echo $id; done
```

I'm printing it right now to see the values but basically whats outputted is

```
35
34
33
```

I'm trying to add them all together but I cant figure out how, some help would be appreciated.

my desired output would be

```
103
```

Comment: If you're using `bash`, you can add values like this: `let result = result + id`. You should prepend your command with a `result=0;`.

Comment: @StefanM I tried doing but it doesnt work

Comment: if you're going to invoke `awk` you might as well do the whole thing in `awk`, ie, let `awk` read the file and add up the values in the first column/field; as for your attempt to use Stefan's suggestion ... you mention `it doesn't work` ... did you get an error? no output? the wrong result?

Comment: @markp-fuso do you mind explaining how I can do that I’m new to bash and I’m trying to use it for future projects because I like it’s simplicity and I’m pretty new to the awk function and when I do that what stefan suggested it outputs 0 = 0 + 35

Comment: See. [Summing values of a column using awk command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28445020/3776858)

Comment: In the `BEGIN` block of awk you define a variable for the sum. In the `END` block you print it. In between, you sum it up.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of ways to do this, a few ideas ...

```
$ cat numbers.dat
35 45 75 76
34 45 53 55
33 34 32 21
```

Tweaking OP's current code:

```
$ sum=0
$ for id in $(awk '{ print $1 }' < numbers.dat); do ((sum+=id)); done
$ echo "${sum}"
102
```

Eliminating `awk`:

```
$ sum=0
$ while read -r id rest_of_line; do sum=$((sum+id)); done < numbers.dat
$ echo "${sum}"
102
```

Using just `awk` (looks like Aivean beat me to it):

```
$ awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}' numbers.dat
102
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }'
```

Test:

```
35 45 75 76
34 45 53 55
33 34 32 21
```

Result:

```
102
```

(`sum(35, 34, 33) = 102`, that's what you want, right?)

Here is the detailed explanation of how this works:

1. `$1` is the first column of the input.
2. `sum` is the variable that holds the sum of all the values in the first column.
3. `END { print sum }` is the action to be performed after all the input has been processed.

So the awk program is basically summing up the first column of the input and printing the result.

---

This answer was partially generated by Davinci Codex model, supervised and verified by me.